# Regex for website and email

Tags: c#, regex, email, web, anchor

Hi i am trying to find out how to make my regex match only url's when not starting with @ ( to prevent it matching email's ) and qoutes to prevent matching html anchor tags ( `<a href="http://www.website.com">www.website.com</a>` ).

Regex:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/`
```

And email to match (email@website.com) and prevent (`<a href="mailto:email@website.com">email@website.com</a>`).

Regex:

```
/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/
```

I keep getting the website regex matching the last part of the email.
How do i prevent the @ before and <> "" '' around my website and prevent <> "" '' on my email regex ?

Coding in C#

Comment: _"I keep getting the website regex matching the last part of the email"_ - that should not happen. Show your code and some example input.

Comment: did you mean https://regex101.com/r/sY6eW6/1 ?

Comment: yes, updated the regex, still matched website inside anchor tags. https://regex101.com/r/sY6eW6/2

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: After long and intense research for a good regex to match email adresses I came up with this very robust and versatile solution:

```
if(adressString.Contains("@") && adressString.Length > 3) // it's an email address
```

Explanation: google and friends agree that there exists no correct regEx which matches all possible email adresses, because there exist no simple/clear/unambiguous definition for a valid email adress.

Comment: Could you add the links from your research? I want to know more about this

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good Regex that can determine that a string is an email address. You're better off just checking for an '@' symbol.

For checking URI's you can just use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uri)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the Regex I use for emails, hope this helps.

```
public static Regex EmailRegex = new Regex(@"^((([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|!|#|$|%|&|'|\*|\+|\-|/|=|\?|\^|_|`|\{|\||\}|~)+(\.([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|!|#|$|%|&|'|\*|\+|\-|/|=|\?|\^|_|`|\{|\||\}|~)+)*)@((((([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\-){0,61}([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])*\.))*([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|\-){0,61}([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])\.(af|ax|al|dz|as|ad|ao|ai|aq|ag|ar|am|aw|au|at|az|bs|bh|bd|bb|by|be|bz|bj|bm|bt|bo|ba|bw|bv|br|io|bn|bg|bf|bi|kh|cm|ca|cv|ky|cf|td|cl|cn|cx|cc|co|km|cg|cd|ck|cr|ci|hr|cu|cy|cz|dk|dj|dm|do|ec|eg|sv|gq|er|ee|et|eu|fk|fo|fj|fi|fr|gf|pf|tf|ga|gm|ge|de|gh|gi|gr|gl|gd|gp|gu|gt|gg|gn|gw|gy|ht|hm|va|hn|hk|hu|is|in|id|ir|iq|ie|im|il|it|jm|jp|je|jo|kz|ke|ki|kp|kr|kw|kg|la|lv|lb|ls|lr|ly|li|lt|lu|mo|mk|mg|mw|my|mv|ml|mt|mh|mq|mr|mu|yt|mx|fm|md|mc|mn|ms|ma|mz|mm|na|nr|np|nl|an|nc|nz|ni|ne|ng|nu|nf|mp|no|om|pk|pw|ps|pa|pg|py|pe|ph|pn|pl|pt|pr|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sh|kn|lc|pm|vc|ws|sm|st|sa|sn|cs|sc|sl|sg|sk|si|sb|so|za|gs|es|lk|sd|sr|sj|sz|se|ch|sy|tw|tj|tz|th|tl|tg|tk|to|tt|tn|tr|tm|tc|tv|ug|uk|ua|ae|gb|us|um|uy|uz|vu|ve|vn|vg|vi|wf|eh|ye|zm|zw|com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|arpa|mobi))|(((([0-9]){1,3}\.){3}([0-9]){1,3}))|(\[((([0-9]){1,3}\.){3}([0-9]){1,3})\])))$");
```

Comment: There are much moreTLDs than that, have a look at http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: True, especially now with all the extra domains like "nike", or "football'. I am using this Regex for almost 4 years and it never failed me. That being said.. I do understand that it is a possibility.